# Core Plot: Add text label to padded area around plotAreaFrame

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I am creating a bar graph and then adding empty space above as follows....

```
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = smallPlotTopOffset; //some number like 25.0
```

I have already added paddingTop to the graph itself, and then used titleDisplacement to move the graph.title into this space.

However, now I would like to add a label between the title and the graph, in the space created by the plotAreaFrame.paddingTop. Is this possible using CPTTextLayers? I've been trying to add a layer, but they seem constrained by the plotAreaFrame (i.e. within the padding). I would like to align my label centred below my graph.title hence trying to use the hostView, rather than just adding a UILabel to the superview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a layer annotation and add it to the graph.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else interested I did this as follows....

```
CPTLayerAnnotation *ann = [[CPTLayerAnnotation alloc] initWithAnchorLayer:self.hostView.hostedGraph.plotAreaFrame];
ann.rectAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop; //to make it the top centre of the plotFrame
ann.displacement = CGPointMake(0, -20.0); //To move it down, below the title

CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"Your Text" style:nil];

ann.contentLayer = textLayer;

[self.hostView.hostedGraph.plotAreaFrame addAnnotation:ann];
```

I think this is the best way, although it'd be better if I could anchor it to below the main title, rather than add a manual displacement.